# Listing items from one controller in another controller's template in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm making a cocktail recipe app in Ember, and I'd like to display a list of existing ingredients inside the template for creating a new recipe. Here are my routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('drinks', {path: '/drinks'});
  this.route('drink', {path: '/drinks/:drink_id'});
  this.route('newdrink', {path: '/drinks/newdrink'});
  this.route('ingredients', {path: '/ingredients'});
  this.route('ingredient', {path: '/ingredients/:ingredient_id'});
  this.route('newingredient', {path: '/ingredients/new'});
});
```

Here's the template for making a new drink:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="newdrink">
   <h3>Create a new drink.</h3>

   <p>{{input type="text" classNames="form-control" placeholder="Enter a new drink." value=newDrinkName action="createDrink"}}</p>
   <p>{{input type="text" classNames="form-control" placeholder="Enter a description." value=newDescription action="createDrink"}}</p>

   <p>Ingredients</p>
   {{#each ingredient in ingredients}}
     {{ingredientName}}<br />
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

Obviously, I'm missing something here. How can I pull up a list of ingredients from the database without nesting the ingredients route inside the drinks route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your routes should probably look like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('drinks', {path: '/drinks'}, function(){
      this.resource('drink', {path: '/drink/:drink_id'});
      this.route('newdrink', {path: '/newdrink'});
  });

  this.route('ingredients', {path: '/ingredients'}, function(){
      this.resource('ingredient', {path: '/ingredient/:ingredient_id'});
      this.route('newingredient', {path: '/new'});
  });
});
```

Now about pulling data from the database - that should be done through a model - and not through the route/controller, meaning there should be a Drink model, referencing ingredients through ember-data/ember-model's hasMany relation - such that it is pulled from the DB automatically.

```
App.Drink = DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr('string'),
      ingredients: DS.hasMany('ingredient')
});
App.Ingredient = DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr('string'),
      Drinks: DS.hasMany('drink')
});
```

Of course you have to define the AJAX interfaces/adapters for these models.
Then you'll be able to do this:

```
App.DrinksDrinkRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('post', params.drink_id);
    }
});
```

This will make the requested drink the model for the template's controller, and will make the ingredients accessible in the templates as model.ingredients (or just ingredients, depending on the controller type).